# asp.net dynamically add GridViewRow

Tags: c#, webforms

I've had a look at this post [How to programmatically insert a row in a GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181158/how-to-programmatically-insert-a-row-in-a-gridview) but i can't get it to add a row i tried it on RowDataBound and then DataBound event but they both aren't working here is my code if someone could show me how to dynamically add a row to the end of GridView not Footer that would be cool anyway here is my code that doesn't work

```
protected void CustomGridView_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = ((GridView)sender).Rows.Count;
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(count+1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert);
    //lblCount.Text = count.ToString();
    // count is correct
    // row.Cells[0].Controls.Add(new Button { Text="Insert" });
    // Error Here adding Button 
    Table table = (Table)((GridView)sender).Rows[0].Parent;
    table.Rows.Add(row);
    // table doesn't add row          
}
```

Comment: In what event you want to add a row to the gridview ?

Comment: I want to add an insert row at the bottom not on the footer so I don't mind which event you use. I also need to add a button to the first column

Comment: Why are you avoiding using the footer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the RowDataBound event, add any Control to a TableCell, and the TableCell to the GridViewRow. Finally add the GridViewRow to the GridView at a specified index:

```
protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{ 
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex+1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Insert); 
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
    cell.ColumnSpan = some_span;
    cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;

    Control c = new Control(); // some control
    cell.Controls.Add(c);
    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    ((GridView)sender).Controls[0].Controls.AddAt(some_index, row);
}
```

This may not be exactly how you need it but it should give you an idea.