# Dynamically create table in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tabular

I have created a table in code behind file dynamically:

[image: This is the screen shot of output right now I am getting]

The code for creating this table is like this:

```
protected void BindGridviewNew(Guid SubscriptionID)
    {
        pnlreapeter.Visible = true;
        gridviewnew.Visible = true;
        List<string> plannig = new List<string>();
        var s = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesPlanning.GetSingleSubVersionTrueFalse(SubscriptionID);
        if (s != null)
        {
            if (s.T1.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T1");
            }
            if (s.T2.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T2");
            }
            if (s.T3.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T3");
            }
            if (s.T4.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T4");
            }
            if (s.T5.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T5");
            }
            if (s.T6.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T6");
            }
            if (s.T7.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T7");
            }
            if (s.T8.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T8");
            }
            if (s.T9.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T9");
            }
            if (s.T10.Value)
            {
                plannig.Add("T10");
            }
        }
        DataTable PlanningDate = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesPlanning.GetRowOfPlanningDate(SubscriptionID);
        DataTable Percentage = m.bussinesCollection.BussinesPlanning.GetAllStudentsForProgressForDocentNew(SubscriptionID);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow newrow;
        newrow = dt.NewRow();
        DataRow Hiddenfield;
        Hiddenfield = dt.NewRow();
        DataRow percentage;
        percentage = dt.NewRow();
        int count = plannig.Count;
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(plannig[j], typeof(string));
            string pl = plannig[j];
            string c = pl.Substring(pl.Length - 1, 1);
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(c);           
            DataRow dr = PlanningDate.Rows[0];
            DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dr[x-1].ToString());
            newrow[plannig[j]] = date.ToShortDateString();
            HiddenField hf = new HiddenField();
            Hiddenfield[plannig[j]] = x;
            DataRow dr1 = Percentage.Rows[0];
            LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
            link.Text = dr1[x].ToString();
            percentage[plannig[j]] = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton) link;

        }
        dt.Rows.Add(newrow);
        dt.Rows.Add(percentage);
       // dt.Rows.Add(Hiddenfield);
        gridviewnew.DataSource = dt;
        gridviewnew.DataBind();
    }
```

The problem here is,as in screen shot I am trying to get link-buttond but the column type is string so that it shows "System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton"

The table I want is like:

```
     T1    |    T2    |    T3
  3/01/2012| 3/03/2012| 3/05/2012
    100    |    50    |   -
```

where on clicking on 100 or 50 a new popup should be displayed.

Can any one help me to create this row..?

Comment: Not an answer, but consider abstracting away all those "if" statements. Perhaps with something as simple as a "for" loop. Statements like that are a real code smell.

Comment: @Djentleman I cant use loop here...I had tried..And this is not an issue here..

Comment: That's fine, was just assuming based off the code I can see. If it works and you definitely won't need to add more (T11, T12, T13 ... Tn) in the future, it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can not add a `LinkButton` to a `DataTable`. What you should do is bind the `DataTable` to the `GridView`, and then manually add a new row to the grid view with the link buttons, I guess in the `RowDataBound` event, or if there is going to be just one row with link buttons, you can add a footer to the grid view.

Check this link [How to programmatically insert a row in a GridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181158/how-to-programmatically-insert-a-row-in-a-gridview)

Comment: @Estenban Yes,This can be one solution..Thanks for the advice..I will try and get back to you..